# convert mp3 to mpz format in a batch file going through all folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, mp3

I use mpz to compress mp3 files as it has better compression than PackMP3. However, it doesn't support wild cards so I have to manually edit batch and add each line individually.

Example of my batch at the moment:

```
mpz c cat.mp3 cat.mpz
cd dog
mpz c dog1.mp3 dog1.mpz
cd..
cd lion
mpz c lion.mp3 lion.mpz
```

I use the following for PackMP3 which DOES support wildcards.

```
SET path=%CD%
SET path=%path:\=\\%
@echo off
for /r %%a in (.) do (
pushd %%a
packMP3 -ver -v2 -np *.mp3 
popd
)
```

Can I modify this to use mpz for all folders including sub folders?

Many thanks

Comment: don't use `path` as variable name. It's a system variable to let Windows know, where to look for executables.

Comment: Think I've cracked it....

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work now using the following:

```
SET path=%CD%
SET path=%path:\=\\%
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a:-d *.mp3') do (
mpz c "%%F" "%%~dpnF.mpz"
)
```